# QuerySelectorAll in React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

**Question:**
I have multiple dropdowns and I am checking to see if any of them are open. How can i do this in React testing library? (I'm going through bunch of tabIndexes and checking through them)

**Issue:**
container.querySelectorAll isn't possible in react testing library.

**Code:**

```
it('should not expand dropdown for multiple view', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      getMockedComponent()
    )

    expect(container).toBeVisible()

    container
      .querySelector('div[tabindex]').forEach(eachAccordian => {
        expect(eachAccordian).toHaveAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false')
      })
 })
```

How can i check all the nodes using React testing library?

Comment: Hi, interesting not sure if this might be of interest https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/526

Comment: Thank you. Any alternatives would be appreciated

Comment: getAllBy, queryAllBy, findAllBy...
https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/cheatsheet/#queries
You have many options, you can also install the testing library dev tools to help you find the correct selectors...

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by using `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

```js
container
      .querySelectorAll('div[tabindex]').forEach(eachAccordian => {
        expect(eachAccordian).toHaveAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false')
      })
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [the React Testing Library queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#queries) instead of `querySelector`. `queryAllBy` should probably get you what you need, where you can select anything with a certain data-test-id or role, and check their attributes from there!

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you give me an example? How can i use `queryAllBy` in this example?

Comment: Like let's say that you give your dropdowns a data-test-id="dropdown", then you can make a custom query helper like the one here (the queryAllByTestId): https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-helpers#custom-queries

Comment: you can get all : const elements = queryAllByLabelText('myLabel')
then lets say you wanna test the if the first one is a certain element, you can use destructering for example: [ firstEl ] = elements
then expect it to have a certain value...

Answer (score 0):

It seems "getByRole" solves many querySelector requirements.

Roles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques#roles